# How to find keyboard height using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

```
let frame = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue) as CGRect
```

does not work. Anybody know why this does not function as expected?

Error: 'NSValue' not convertible to 'CGRect'

Keep in mind that something like:

```
let curve = (info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as NSValue) as UInt
```

works fine.

Edit: Even Apple documentation indicates this is a glitch because of the following comment in Cocoa for `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`

```
// NSValue of CGRect
```

Edit2: The debugger defines it as an NSConcreteValue. How can I convert it to a CGRect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let frame = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope Apple changes this for consistency purposes in the future!

Comment: There's no inconsistency, this is how would you do it in Objective-C, NSValue is not toll-free bridged to its wrapped value. So this is a NSValue detail rather than a Swift problem

Comment: The cocoa frameworks are being modified to allow for consistency in Swift too ;)

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'info' ? i'm getting this error :

Comment: `info` is the userInfo dictionary from the notification.

Answer (score 1):

**To use keyboardFrame height with NSNotificationCenter**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(self.keyboardWasShown(_:)),
                                                         name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                                                         object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                                         name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
                                                         object: nil)


    }



    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.constBottomLayout.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
        })
    }


    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        // self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        self.constBottomLayout.constant = 0
    }
```